# How to send a notification after inserting data from microservice to another?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, entitylisteners

am currently trying to send some entity attributes to from a microservice A to another microservice B to trigger a scheduled event in B and each microservice has its own database.
to detect the insert i used EntityListner and
Am using feignClient to communicate between the two but my question how can i send the "notification" from A to B?

Comment: Use a message queue or similar, when you wish to update fire an event from Microservicr A and in Microservice B register topic listeners and receive event there later you can do business logic processing in Microservice B

Comment: do you have any example on how to do it ? am newbie at microservices